# Destroying a Running Thread and Reinitialize in a new variable

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am making a remote application in java

1. The UDP Server Thread without ds.close() method

   ```
   public class UDPThreadServer extends Thread { 

   private DatagramSocket datagramSocket; 
   private DatagramPacket datagramPacket; 
   private byte[] data; // the array of bytes which will store data here



   public UDPThreadServer() {



       // initialize variables
       // setup something
   }

   public void run() { // overriding run method

       while(true) { // or while(!ds.isClosed())

           datagramSocket.receive(dp); // receive data and assign to byte array


       }
   }

   }
   ```
2. The Main Program

   ```
   public class Main {

   public static UDPThreadServer udpThread; // the udp server running in thread

   public static void main(String[] args) {


      udpThread = new UDPThreadServer();

      udpThread.start(); // start the thread

      System.in.read();

   }


   }
   ```

Let's say I have this method

```
public static void newThread() {

     udpThread = new UDPThreadServer(); // destroy and reinitialize thread  without calling    udpThread.stopUDP();

}
```

I am curious about Thread Safety in java.

Is it safe to call newThread() method???

Comment: I think your newThread() will create a new Instance of UDPThreadedServer class and than old one will be stopped and will be marked for garbage collection...

Comment: Yes, it will create a new thread. And the old thread will stop.

Comment: @amit and Glenn you are both incorrect. It will create a new Thread, but not start it, and it won't do anything to the old one.

Comment: You mean, the old thread still there? in Memory?

Comment: Certainly. Nothing there to stop it.

Comment: @EJP did I or Glenn ever said that new Thread will automatically start..... of course we need to start it explicitly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what you do inside the constructor. Your code doesn't start a new thread.

If Code that is safe to be called by multiple threads simultaneously then it is thread safe.

**Local Variables**

Local variables are stored in each thread's own stack. That means that local variables are never shared between threads.
And hence they are always thread safe.

**Local Object References**

Local references to objects are a bit different. 
The reference itself is not shared. The object referenced however, is not stored in each thread's local stack.

All objects are stored in the shared heap. If an object created locally never escapes the method it was created in, it is thread safe.

Here is an example of a thread safe local object:

```
public void someMethod(){

  LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

  localObject.callMethod();
  method2(localObject);
}

public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
  localObject.setValue("value");
}
```

**Object Members (fields)**

Object members (member variables) are stored on the heap along with the object. 
Therefore, if two threads call a method on the same object instance and this method updates object members, the method is not thread safe.

Fields are made safe using any of the below conditions

1. Make it volatile
2. Make it final (and it is accessed after the constructor has completed). [more here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml)
3. The field access is protected by means of a lock. (Using synchronized or an explicit lock)
4. Using Immutability

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are sharing something between two instances of thread. If you are, then you need to handle access to shared variable through synchronized access. e.g. If you want to read data using datagramSocket through multiple threads then you can to design separate class, provide synchronized read method which will read data from this socket. Pass the instance of this class to all thread. Now as method is synchronized you can read data in thread safe way.

Answer (score 1):

```
udpThread = new UDPThreadServer(); // destroy and reinitialize thread  without calling    udpThread.stopUDP();
```

The comment is incorrect. That line of code won't destroy anything; it won't 'reinitialize' anything; and it won't start a new thread. All it does is change the value of the variable `udpThread`, plus whatever side-effects the constructor of `UDPThreadServer` may have.

> Is it safe to call newThread() method???

It is certainly thread-safe, if that's what you mean. It is also pointless.

Comment: I forgot to put udpThread.start() :)

Hmm. What will happen if i call the newThread() ???

Comment: @Glennascual (1) You forgot to put it where? (2) newThread() just creates a new instance of `UDPThreadServer` and does whatever its constructor does.

Comment: "An un referenced object is available for Garbage Collection", is A thread exception to this rule ? What will happen to old thread object since there is no one referring to it any more..... ? plz reply!!!

Comment: @amit as long as the thread keeps running, the JVM has a reference to it, so it will not be garbage-collected.